# Can the decompistion of one carbonate inhibt the decomposition of another carbonate?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

If two different carbonates of Group II, are mixed in equal amounts and then heated could one of the carbonates decomposition inhibt the other ones decomposition?

I don't understand how it would because (as far as I am aware) the reaction is not an equilibrium.

However I was told that if:

> Equal masses of barium carbonate and magnesium carbonate powders are mixed together, and then heated using a Bunsen burner flame until there is no further change.

then

> The residue left after heating reacts with aqueous hydrochloric acid to produce carbon dioxide.

This suggests that not all of the carbonate decomposes. However (from Wikepedia)

- Maximum temerature of a Bunsen burner flame is 1560 degrees celcius
- Thermal decompistion of barium carbonate starts at 1360 degrees celcius
- Thermal decompistion of magnesium chloride starts at 350 degrees celcius and is considered complete above 900 degrees celcius

This suggests that all the carbonate decomposes, however I am skeptical of this (Wikapedia) data.

So is thermal decompistion being inhibted? Or is barium carbonate simply not undergoing full decompistion (Wikapedia data is wrong)?

*I couldn't find anything about it but maybe barum carbonate, like magnesium carbonate needs a much higher temperature than stated to fully decompose?*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunsen_burner mentions that 1560 is max. for Tirrill burner not bunsen. You simply won't make the mixture hot enough.

Comment: Barium carbonate DOES NOT decompose on heating with a bunsen burner.

Comment: @Mewton barium carbonate does decompose on heating but the temperature required for its decomposition is not provided by the Bunsen burner